# How (if possible) to raise gaming fps?

Tags: graphics, games, steam, framerate

I was trying to play Civ 5 and Borderlands 2 via steam and had terrible frame rates. BL2 was far worse, but Civ 5 was also pretty bad. Is this just because I'm running Ubuntu, or could there be a correctable issue causing it?

I'm using a laptop, so I can't take it apart to find part numbers, but according to the "about your computer" option, I have:

1. 3.6 gigabytes of RAM,
2. Intel® Core™ i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 processor,
3. Intel® Sandybridge Mobile for graphics, I don't know if this is was Windows 10 was running, I have no way of checking,
4. 64-bit OS, 14.04.3

Everything  seems to be working alright outside of gaming, no lag or freezing. Any way to fix this?

Results of `lspci |grep VGA`:

`VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`

Comment: can you [edit] your post and add the output of `lspci |grep VGA`

Comment: Added the output

Comment: Intel HD 3000 integrated graphics are not really suitable for gaming I'm afraid, and being on a laptop doesn't give you room to upgrade. You may have better luck with classic games that don't require modern hardware, or casual games that don't require much GPU power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the reasons why the games are not working as you want them to.

### Civ 5

In the Steam store system in System Requirements tab notes that `Intel Integrated video chipsets (GMA 9XX, HD 3XXX) will not run Civilization V for SteamOS and Linux, and are unsupported.` You have a `Intel® HD Graphics 3000 integrated`

[image]

### Borderlands 2

In the Steam store in System Requirements tab notes that `Intel Integrated video chipsets and ATI chipsets are currently unsupported for Borderlands 2 Linux.` You have a `Intel® HD Graphics 3000 integrated`

[image]

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. I assumed it'd be about the same as the windows requirements. That puts a bit of a damper on things. Oh well, I'll find something that works better soon. Thanks!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer did help you, please don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

From my standpoint it looks like your specs are below what they should be for those games (I could be wrong). Your graphics card is only using 400megabytesish (that is where the other .4ish ram is going).

---

- In your bios see if you can devote a little more ram to your onboard graphics (this is also a problem you have no dedicated graphics card)
- If you can allow your graphics card to use more ram you might have to add more ram to your laptop since you are borrowing from the other 3.6gb
- In-Game turn down all the settings to low and disable things like AA.
- install htop `sudo apt-get install htop` and run it in a terminal `htop` while one of your games are running. (this will allow you to see how your ram and cpu are doing while in-game)
- See if the proprietary drivers under Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers helps (if their is any available for your laptop).